# Unit Test to check occurence of a large xml snippet inside a large xml file

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, ms-word

I have an application which outputs a large [Word XML Formatted xml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) file (along 200000 lines) based on numerous parameters.

I want to write unit tests to check the contents of the output file based on combinations of parameters.

I need a way to check for the occurrence of a large xml snippet inside the output file, WITHOUT problems related to formatting (whitespaces outside tags, tabs, new lines etc):

```
//that would be perfect
assertXMLContains("Checking if outputted xml contains the needed xml snipped",
                       outputtedXml, mySnipXML);
```

The excellent XMLUnit ( http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/ ) provides a way to assert for equality of xml contents only, so it seems I cannot use it.

Below is an example of the kind of xml snippets we need to search for. They can be a concatenation of w:p or w:r elements not necessarily grouped inside a parent element...

```
         <w:r w:rsidR="00EE0BED" w:rsidRPr="009322FC">
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman Bold" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman Bold"/>
                            <w:b/>
                            <w:caps/>
                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                            <w:lang w:eastAsia="en-GB"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t>Annex V</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:r w:rsidR="00B40C3C" w:rsidRPr="009322FC">
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman Bold" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman Bold"/>
                            <w:b/>
                            <w:caps/>
                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                            <w:lang w:eastAsia="en-GB"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t>II</w:t>
                    </w:r>
```

Comment: Can't you just use XPath to look for the required elements?

Comment: I do not think so. The above example is just a small snippet. Usually, we would search for dozens of <w:r> elements in a specific order, with nothing to discriminate between them except the contents of their <w:t> element  (i.e. <w:t>Annex V</w:t>)

Answer (score 0):

That's not what most people mean by the term "unit testing"...

The W3C test suites for XSLT and XQuery (which are publicly available) have moved away from comparing equality of XML results, because that's so inflexible, and for the reasons you describe. Instead they use a system of assertions, typically XPath expressions, rather like Selenium.

Comment: I agree this is closer to Integration testing. XPath would be extremely clumsy to use, though. We usually are looking for dozens of <w:r> elements in a specific order, with nothing to discriminate between them except the contents of their <w:t> element (i.e. <w:t>Annex V</w:t>). And that is just for one test.

Comment: You may be cramming too much into one test. If you want to test that everything in a large result document is as expected, you may be better off canonicalizing the result and comparing canonical forms. That's what we used to do. But we now try to have more and smaller tests, whose success can be gauged by a handful of XPath expressions.

Comment: Unfortunately, canonicalizing a 200000 lines Word file adds quite a toll on the test. Also, the tabulations in the snippet xml need to match the ones in the bigger Word document and this is not solved by canonicalization.

Comment: As I said, I think you are trying to do too much in one test.